# Client and Server connection with different port numbers?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, client-server, port

I have set up a client and a server using sockets in python where my client sends data to the server, servers performs an operation, then returns some data to the client. Originally both the client and server were to have the same port number (9999). My issue currently is that I have to change the port of the server to 19999, and when I try to run, it does not work. The client is able to send data if its port is also changed to 19999, but it does not work if client is 9999 and server is 19999, which is what I need. New to networking systems so would appreciate any useful links to information or advice.

pic of client (left) and server (right)

[image]

Comment: "_Originally both the client and server were to have the same port number (9999)._" You should just let the client get an ephemeral port. It is unnecessary and wrong to try to have both use the same port number.

Comment: @RonMaupin the ports to be used were specified in the problem description not chosen by me. Is it possible to establish a connection between port 9999 and 19999?

Comment: "_It is possible to establish a connection between port 9999 and 19999?_" Yes, of course it is. The port numbers on each side can be different, and they almost always are. You get a random, ephemeral port number when you connect to a web site with a well know port number 443 for HTML. It sound like the code is purposely trying to do something pointless and detrimental.

Comment: @RonMaupin its just an interview coding project to see if I can jump into new task as i havent done network programming before. Would you say this link is wrong then? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694551/do-client-and-server-need-to-use-same-port-to-connect?rq=1). The top reply here states that they must be the same. For reference, for the first part i was told to make them both on the same port, then told server should now run on 19999. So i am assuming I have to keep the client on 9999 since that was not specified

Comment: @RonMaupin i attached an edit with the code of the sockets if it provides more context

Answer (score 1):

Normally, clients will use an [*ephemeral port*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) for its local port, and connect to the server port. Your client code is attempting to connect to port 9999, which is not the server port, which explains why it is not working. You need to connect to port 19999, since that is the port the server is listening on.

Using an unbound socket causes the client to choose an ephemeral port for its local address when making a connection. If you want the client to bind to a specific port, use `bind` before you call `connect`.

```
# bind locally to 9999
local_addr = (host, 9999)
s.bind(local_addr)

# connect to 19999
remote_addr = (host, 19999)
s.connect(remote_addr)
```

Comment: appreciate the reply but this isnt necessarily what I am trying to do. If i make this change i am unable to run multiple clients locally on the server because the connections are all trying to use the same port.

Comment: @RonMaupin just read the first specification and it never specified what port my client has to use so ill just be changing it to 9999. thank you both for the help

Comment: @wetmoney Just to be clear, you stated *but it does not work if client is 9999 and server is 19999, which is what I need*. My answer explains why what you were trying didn't work, and how to change it so that it would work, because you had stated it was needed. The limitation is exactly how you stated, which is why clients typically use an ephemeral port.