# Java - How to mention protocol family?

Tags: java, sockets

In C, [protocol family](https://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) is mentioned as first parameter.

For ex:

`socket(AF_INET,,)` for ipv4

`socket(AF_PACKET,,)` used for packet sniffing

---

Python supports three address families, `AF_INET`, `AF_INET6` & `AF_UNIX`

---

In Java, below syntax does not allow mentioning protocol family,

```
ServerSocket()
ServerSocket(int port)
ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)
ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)

Socket()
Socket(InetAddress address, int port)
Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
Socket(Proxy proxy)
Socket(SocketImpl impl)
Socket(String host, int port)
Socket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
```

---

1) On which protocol family stack, does Java enable socket communication?

2) Does Java allow explicit mentioning of protocol family for socket communication?

Comment: Does it need to be passed to the constructor? Are you having a specific issue connecting to a socket?

Comment: @cricket_007 Protocol family should be picked, before socket is created. I did not get your point. In C, `socket(AF_INET,,)` api uses *selector pattern* to pick the protocol family based on the argument passed and bind the corresponding protocol family library to C application in run time.

Answer (score 3):

Java does not support AF_UNIX or AF_PACKET at all. All the socket classes support AF_INET and AF_INET6 only, and do so automatically depending on whether an AF_INET6 stack exists or not.

Comment: `Socket(InetAddress address, int port)` api in java is an abstraction over `InputStream` & `OutputStream` byte based stream IO. How does byte based stream IO understand *tcp port number* and *inet address*?

Comment: Hey so @overexchange it's based on what kind of address you give it.

Comment: @overxchange You have it upside down. Input and output streams are themselves abstractions. It would be more accurate to say that the socket input and output streams are abstractions over the socket.

Comment: @EJP You are right, it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12715760/3317808)

Comment: Well it isn't really, and confirming one Stack Overflow answer via another isn't a valid procedure.